# Is it possible to open an antd image preview with a button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd

I want to open the preview of an Image in antd without clicking on the image thumbnail itself (e.g. by clicking on a button):

```
import React from 'react';
import {Image, Button} from 'antd';

const Foo: React.Fc<any> = (props) => {

const [isPreviewVisible,setPreviewVisible] = useState<boolean>(false);

return (
  <div>
       <Image 
        // something like this 
        // isPreviewVisible={isPreviewVisible} 
        src="some url"
       />
       <Button onClick={()=>setState(!isPreviewVisible)}>Click me!</Button>
  </div>
  );
};
```

I would like to implement it similar to the code above, but could not find any way to do it.

Edit: I want to control/toggle the visibility of the preview with a state.

Comment: like a tooltip?

Comment: not quite, but similar. i was trying to use the already existing preview functionality of the image component of antd itself, but in a more "controlled" way. in my example i wanted to control the visibility of the preview with a state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
function ImageDemo() {
  const [isPreviewVisible, setPreviewVisible] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      <Image
        width={200}
        preview={{
          visible: isPreviewVisible,
          onVisibleChange: (visible, prevVisible) => setPreviewVisible(visible),
        }}
        src="https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/jkjgkEfvpUPVyRjUImniVslZfWPnJuuZ.png"
      />
      <Button onClick={() => setPreviewVisible(!isPreviewVisible)}>
        Click me
      </Button>
    </>
  );
}
```

I've also implemented an example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-meyy1u) you can check it out: